# Router OpenVPN client connected, but remote VPN machines not visible

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, vlan

My goal is to connect my Asus RT-68 router to remote VPN network, so LAN computers can access remote ones.
Remote OpenVPN server is run on Zentyal Linux distro.

My LAN address range is 100.100.0.0/24 and remote address range is 192.168.0.0/24. When using OpenVPN client software on a LAN computer (Tunnelblick for OSX in my case), it gets connected to the server and i can connect to remote machines as expected. Routes look ok:

```
$ traceroute 192.168.0.30
traceroute to 192.168.0.30 (192.168.0.30), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  192.168.160.1 (192.168.160.1)  10.490 ms  9.074 ms  8.067 ms
2  192.168.0.30 (192.168.0.30)  9.584 ms  9.784 ms  7.616 ms
```

I can also see the corresponding interface in my ifconfig output:

```
tap0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 8e:bf:97:06:50:a2 
inet 192.168.160.4 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.160.255
media: autoselect
status: active
open (pid 22745)
```

So I'm using the same ovpn configuration (including certificates) on the router (IP 100.100.0.1) and web interface indicates that it got connected ok. I can also see a new interface in ifconfig output on the router:

```
tap15      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:13:AE:AE:33:C9  
       inet addr:192.168.160.10  Bcast:192.168.160.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
       RX packets:4553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:355471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
       RX bytes:522084 (509.8 KiB)  TX bytes:78850779 (75.1 MiB)
```

But when I try to ping or traceroute remote VPN machines, they're unaccessible. Traceroute takes forever and looks like this:

```
# traceroute 192.168.0.30
traceroute to 192.168.0.30 (192.168.0.30), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
1  *  *  *
2  *  *  *
3  *  *  *
4  *  *  *
5  *  192.168.160.10 (192.168.160.10)  1394.990 ms !H  *
6  *  *  *
7  *  192.168.160.10 (192.168.160.10)  23.796 ms !H  *
8  *  *  *
9  *  *  *
10  *
```

And so on. So no remote computers are visible neither for router, not for LAN computers.

Netstat output is:

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
77.37.206.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 vlan2
192.168.160.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tap15
192.168.0.0     192.168.160.1   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tap15
100.100.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
77.37.206.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
0.0.0.0         77.37.206.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 vlan2
```

Asus firmware version is latest: 3.0.0.4.378_9313. Firewall is disabled.

What am I missing here? 
I guess it's some extra routing that should be configured.

Comment: Nobody checks route table with a `traceroute`, you are missing basics. Reinvestigate.

Comment: Route table on my router looks like this:

Comment: Added `netstat -rn` output to the question body

Comment: @drookie can you please give some clues on what to investigate?

Comment: You need to check if 100.100.0.0/24 is aware about where to look for 192.168.0.0/24, and vice versa, this is done with `netstat -rn` on both end. You need to check that on both routers (first) and remote computers (after routers). Then you need to check if each router can ping remote router internal interface. Then same stuff with some random machine in the LAN.  Nobody can say that your question isn't made thoroughly, but in fact it does contain lot of irrelevant information, and doesn't contain important one. `traceroute` isn't needed here at all.

Comment: And, by the way, addressing sheme 100.100.0/24 for LAN is out of RFC1918 bounds, it's actually a piece of a public internet. You really need to use something standard for internal addressing.